# Excel Index Match Small - Formula working only in manual mode

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to adapt a formula for my needs, but I can seem to make it work only in Manual calculation mode for some reason. If Automatic mode is selected formula returns 0 on every row.

In essense formula is returning ALL matches based on the Blue keyword in column I matched in the sheet DIL-2018-08-14, column H. It all works great ONLY in manual mode and only after manual recalculation on every cell.

Can someone advise if there is was to avoid this and make it wortk in automatic mode as well.

The formula is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('DIL-2018-08-14'!$H$9:$H$502,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(LEFT(I8,FIND(" ",I8)-1),'DIL-2018-08-14'!$H$9:$H$502)),ROW('DIL-2018-08-14'!$H$9:$H$502)-ROW('DIL-2018-08-14'!$H$9)+1),COUNTIF($J$7:J8,"*"&LEFT(I8,FIND(" ",I8)-1)&"*")+1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is an array, so are you pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: It appears the COUNTIF is looping on itself, which is causing the issue. The new question now remains - how to increment the k param of the small function (currently using the COUNTIF) so that it resets on every new blue keyword match from 1?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to fix it on your own:

- Change the whole formula to something with hardcoded values like this:

`=IFERROR(INDEX('DIL-2018-08-14'!$H$9:$H$502,1,1),"")`

- Check whether it works.
- Start rebuilding the formula until it fails, building a step by step solution with less hard coded values.
- See where it fails.
- Think of a solution.

Comment: Also, you can highlight sections of the formula(that would exist as formula in their own right) and press F9 to see what the result is, so `=if(a1:a10="a",row(a1:a10))` would show as `{1,5,9}` if a1,5,9 were "a"

Comment: Thank you for the good ideas. Following the approach I found out that the COUNTIF is looping on itself, which is causing the issue. The new question now is - how to increment the k param of the SMALL function (currently using the COUNTIF) so that it resets on every new blue keyword match from 1? Or maybe I can get it to increment with -1 by having the total number of matches.

Comment: @AntonAndonov - glad you could manage it. Concerning the new question - try to make a minimal, complete & verifyable example and ask it again - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I finaly nailed it! This is the working formula in case anyone needs it. I replaced the COUNTIF with SUM of the occurances of the blue keywords in the static column I, which is reseting the counter for every new keyword.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DIL!$H$9:$H$503,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(LEFT(I8,FIND(" ",I8)-1),DIL!$H$9:$H$503)),ROW(DIL!$H$9:$H$503)-ROW(DIL!$H$9)+1),SUM(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(LEFT(I8,FIND(" ",I8)-1),$I$6:I8)))))),"")
```